# KeyError when checking if graph path is valid

Tags: python, graph-algorithm

I am implementing a graph class and would like to write a function that calculates whether a given path is valid. I'm getting a key error in my is_path_valid function.

My graph is represented as {a:{b:c}} where a and b are a vertex connected to each other, and c is the weight of the edge

Given:

```
{0: {1: 5.0, 2: 10.0}, 1: {3: 3.0, 4: 6.0}, 3: {2: 2.0, 4: 2.0, 5: 2.0}, 4: {6: 6.0}, 5: {6: 2.0}, 7: {9: 1.0}, 8: {7: 2.0, 9: 4.0}}
```

Vertex 2 to 3 is a valid path.

My graph class:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, n):
        """
        Constructor
        :param n: Number of vertices
        """
        self.order = n
        self.size = 0
        self.vertex = {}

    def insert_edge(self, u, v, w): #works fine
        if u in self.vertex and v < self.order:
            if not v in self.vertex[u]:
                self.vertex[u][v] = w
                self.size += 1
        elif u not in self.vertex and u < self.order and v < self.order:
            self.vertex[u] = {}
            self.vertex[u][v] = w
            self.size += 1
        else:
            raise IndexError

    def is_path_valid(self, path):
        while True:
            try:
                s = path.pop(0)
            except IndexError:
                break
            if path:
                d = path.pop(0)
            if s not in self.vertex and d not in self.vertex[s]: #ERROR
                return False
            s = d
        return True
```

My main function:

```
def main():

    g = Graph(10)
    g.insert_edge(0,1,5.0)
    g.insert_edge(0,2,10.0)
    g.insert_edge(1,3,3.0)
    g.insert_edge(1,4,6.0)
    g.insert_edge(3,2,2.0)
    g.insert_edge(3,4,2.0)
    g.insert_edge(3,5,2.0)
    g.insert_edge(4,6,6.0)
    g.insert_edge(5,6,2.0)
    g.insert_edge(7,9,1.0)
    g.insert_edge(8,7,2.0)
    g.insert_edge(8,9,4.0)

True(g.is_path_valid([0, 2]))
True(g.is_path_valid([2, 3]))
True(g.is_path_valid([0, 2, 3]))
False(g.is_path_valid([0, 1, 8]))
False(g.is_path_valid([0, 4, 3]))

    print(g.vertex) #to see the graph
    print(g.is_path_valid([2,3]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My error:

```
if s not in self.vertex and d not in self.vertex[s]:
KeyError: 2
```

Comment: `if s not in self.vertex and d not in self.vertex[s]:` is contradictory, if the first part is true `s not in self.vertex` then by definition `self.vertex[s]` will raise the above mentioned error. Maybe you mean to have an `or` here?

Comment: Good catch, when it is or though, g.is_path_valid([2,3]) goes into the if statement and returns False instead of True. Do you see any work around for that? Even though 2 is not a key, it is a value and connects to 3.

Comment: I see what the problem is, you have something that you call `vertex` when you use it as they were `edges` but in fact what you store in this dictionary are arcs. The difference between an arc and an edge is that the former is oriented. Which means that (2, 3) is not equal to (3, 2), they are different arcs. In fact, `[2, 3]` is not a valid path because the arc (2, 3) is not part of your graph, on the other hand `[3, 2]` would be a valid path because (3, 2) is an arc that exists in your graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just are mixing together arcs and edges which leads to some unexpected things happening, you have to choose between either of the two.

On the other hand you can have an oriented graph and still have a function that will add "edges" in the sense that it will add both arcs (u, v) and (v, u). I have edges in quotes because they're not really edges (the term edge only have meaning in a non-oriented graph).

```py
from collections import defaultdict

class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self._arcs = defaultdict(dict)

    def insert_arc(self, u, v, w):
        self._arcs[u][v] = w

    def is_arc(self, u, v):
        return u in self._arcs and v in self._arcs[u]

    def is_path_valid(self, path):
        for u, v in zip(path, path[1:]):
            if not self.is_arc(u, v):
                return False
        return True

    # We add the notion of "edges" with the following methods:

    def insert_edge(self, u, v, w):
        self.insert_arc(u, v, w)
        self.insert_arc(v, u, w)

    @property
    def edges(self):
        return {((u, v), w) for u, Nu in self._arcs.items() for v, w in Nu.items() if self.is_edge(u, v)}

    def is_edge(self, u, v):
        is_symetric = self.is_arc(u, v) and self.is_arc(v, u)
        if not is_symetric: 
            return False
        return self._arcs[u][v] == self._arcs[v][u]
```

You can now add either edges or arcs to your graph:

```py
g = Graph()

# This is an arc:
g.insert_arc(1, 8, 1.)

# Weight is not symmetric but this still look like an edge:
g.insert_arc(1, 0, 3.)
g.insert_arc(0, 1, 2.)

# These are all symmetric (ie. "edges")
g.insert_edge(1, 2, 7.)
g.insert_edge(2, 3, 5.)
g.insert_edge(0, 3, 13.)

# we added an arc (1, 8): 
print(g.is_path_valid([1, 8])) # True
print(g.is_path_valid([8, 1])) # False

# All true:
print(g.is_path_valid([0, 3]))  
print(g.is_path_valid([2, 3]))
print(g.is_path_valid([0, 1, 2, 3, 0]))

# Adding one step make this false since (0, 2) doesn't exist:
print(g.is_path_valid([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2]))
```

We can use the `edges` property to find all "edges" (symmetric arcs with the same weight in both directions):

```py
>>> print(g.edges)
{((3, 0), 13.0), ((3, 2), 5.0), ((2, 1), 7.0), ((1, 2), 7.0), ((2, 3), 5.0), ((0, 3), 13.0)}
```

Notice how `(0, 1)` is not part of the set of edges, that's because the link exists in both directions but the weight is not the same. The arc `(1, 8)` is obviously not here as `(8, 1)` is not part of the graph.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but there's one issue. So I am trying to implement edges, no orientation. self.is_path_valid([2,3]) should return True, but returns False. 2 is not a key in my dictionary, so that might be an issue. 2 is stored as a value in the key 3.

Comment: Yes that’s exactly the issue, that’s why you need to add both references in your dictionary (as the code shows for u and v in insert_edge)